# ExtJs 3.4 updating data in XTemplate

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, extjs3

I have a panel which is has template defined like this:

```
this.personalPanel = new Ext.Panel({
    title: 'Personal',
    autoScroll: true,
    tpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
        '<div class="addressbook-preview-panel">',
        '<div><span>ID     </span>{[this.encode(values.id, "mediumtext")]}</div>',
        '<div><span>PIN    </span>{[this.encode(values.pin, "mediumtext")]}</div>',
        '<div><span>Address</span>{address_mm}</div>',
        '</div>', {
            encode: function (value, type, prefix) {
                return self.encode.apply(self, arguments);
            }
        })
});
```

Now initially on load only ID and PIN are loaded, and I would like to fill in Address upon AJAX request. The problem is when I try to update the field, existing values get overwritten and I only see Address (I have shortened the call to `this.personalPanel`, but in reality it is called from another file, not the one it is defined on).

```
this.personalPanel.update({address_mm: something.something});
```

I tried to look into `tplWriteMode` since it is set to `overwrite` by default, but that didn't help as other options just add another template before or after the existing content so I have a duplicate then.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using below code

```
this.personalPanel.update({address_mm: something.something});
```

So it will overtire the previous object/data. You need to use [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with previous one data and new one data. Like below

```
newData = Object.assign({
    address_mm: 'this new address'
}, panel.custObj))
```

**Code Snippet and [Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/2u7u)**

```js
Ext.onReady(function () {
    var personalPanel = new Ext.Panel({
        title: 'Personal',
        autoScroll: true,
        id: 'personalPnl',
        custObj:{},//custom property
        buttons: [{
            text: 'Refresh Data',
            handler: function (btn) {
                //This will be your second load data, you can merge with same custome object,
                //you need to do becuase you are taking data in panel, you are doing dynamically
                var panel = Ext.getCmp('personalPnl'),
                    newData = Object.assign({
                        address_mm: 'this new address'
                    }, panel.custObj);

                panel.update(newData);
            }
        }],
        tpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
            '<div class="addressbook-preview-panel">',
            '<div><span>ID  :</span>{[this.encode(values.id, "mediumtext")]}</div>',
            '<div><span>PIN :</span>{[this.encode(values.pin, "mediumtext")]}</div>',
            '<div><span>Address :</span>{address_mm}</div>',
            '</div>', {
                encode: function (value, type, prefix) {
                    return value; //self.encode.apply(self, arguments);
                }
            })
    });

    personalPanel.render(document.body);
    // this is will be your first load data
    personalPanel.custObj = {
        id: 1,
        pin: '4501111'
    };
    personalPanel.update(personalPanel.custObj);
});
```

Comment: This does work when you have initial data ready, as you have with `data: {...}`, however this is a dynamic property, and it is initially empty. After first request it gets populated (thus `initialConfig.data` is empty before first request), and second request fills out the address. Since config is empty, update with `Object.assign` also rewrites it because it appends to empty data

Comment: as mentioned in question initially on load only ID and PIN are loaded, how is your data coming ? id,pin and other things ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. On page load an AJAX is ran populating ID and PIN, then another AJAX on element pick which should populate address

Comment: ok there is one solution you can assign your first object inside of panel like `panel.custObj= {}` and in second load you can merge with that

Comment: As per you are updating dynamically then you need to maintain one custom variable inside of panel or global.I have updated my answer please check. As you are using update method, internally it is calling `overwrite : function(el, values, returnElement){
        el = Ext.getDom(el);
        el.innerHTML = this.applyTemplate(values);
        return returnElement ? Ext.get(el.firstChild, true) : el.firstChild;
    }` and this `overwrite` will update your dom element.